# Block USB, based on Volume/Capacity

Tags: c#, windows, usb, block, volume

I want to block a USB based on volume using C#. Like I want to block USB stick if capacity is greater than 8GB.

Look there is a method to block USB on PC using registry. but this will make USB undetectable so I can not get volume information.

I want to do that If my client program is running on some machine and I put restriction that USB capacity >=8GB should be restricted, so my C# code should safely remove the USB and should now show any balloon, I mean silently remove it.

Comment: This question needs a little more context. Can you revise your question to explain what the program is doing and where USB blocking fits into it?

Comment: Registry method will make USB undetectable, so I can not get volume information.

Comment: What registry method are you using?

Comment: It seems like you are diving into driver space here...

Comment: @kyndigs Registry Method open run and paste "REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f" and for enabling "REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f"

Comment: Is there any way to hook system32\DRIVERS\USBSTOR.SYS ???

Comment: I got very interesting article; have a look http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usbeject.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are disabling the USBSTOR key, then you prevent "ACCESS" to it, that includes gathering information from it.

I suggest you look here: [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480.aspx)

Using this you can catch when the USB is entered and then get the drive letter and use the [DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363249.aspx) to gather information on it, then you can disable it using your registry method.

Comment: Since the question is tagged as C#, it would be good to know if there are .NET equivalents for these Win32 events too.

Comment: You can use the System.Management namespace shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/02/05/WMIMan/default.aspx

Comment: Furthermore how to get the Event of Inserting USB so that my program get activated?

Comment: Look here for some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772337/drive-is-mounted-or-changes-state-wm-devicechange-for-net

Comment: I have found very interesting article have a look please http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usbeject.aspx