# GET USB unique ID on putting or removing the key

Tags: c#, usb, wmi, wmi-query

I need to get the unique USB ID (not a Volume serial number ) on putting/removing the USB. But in all case "PNPDeviceID" is always empty.
The code which I used is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    const string QUERY = @"select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance isa 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and (TargetInstance.DriveType=2)"; 
    Program p = new Program(); 
    ManagementEventWatcher w = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery(QUERY));
    w.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(p.OnWMIEvent); 
    w.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
    w.Stop();
}

public void OnWMIEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyData p = e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"]; 
    if (p != null) 
    {
        ManagementBaseObject mbo = p.Value as ManagementBaseObject;
        PropertyData deviceid = mbo.Properties["DeviceID"]; 
        PropertyData drivetype = mbo.Properties["DriveType"];
        PropertyData driveSerial = mbo.Properties["VolumeSerialNumber"];
        PropertyData driveGUID = mbo.Properties["PNPDeviceID"];

        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", "DeviceID",deviceid.Value); 
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", "DriveType",drivetype.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", "DriveSerial", driveSerial.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", "driveGUID", driveGUID.Value);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Source is:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772337/detect-when-drive-is-mounted-or-changes-state-wm-devicechange-for-wpf)

I Can get the UNIQUE USB id with the following code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");

foreach(ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", "PNPDeviceID", currentObject.Properties["PNPDeviceID"].Value);            
}
```

So please can you tell me how can I combine them to receive PNPDeviceId (USB GUID) when I put/remove the USB stick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you query directly the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class and you don't get values for the `PNPDeviceID` property, neither you will get values when you use this class inside of the wmi event. instead you can use the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class with the `__InstanceOperationEvent` intrinsic event.

```
Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_DiskDrive' and TargetInstance.InterfaceType='USB'
```